# LinearLayout within 2 LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have to develop one expandablelistview android example. I have a design problem. Please help me. How can i resolve this error?
please refer this screenshot:[current o/p](http://screencast.com/t/LYfkXNiWs)  please refer my screenshot and give me solution for this.[image]

I wish to apply this format:

```
* Order info
Payment_method:
      Payment_method
Subtotal
      Subtotal
* CustomerInfo
Firstname
      Firstname
Lastname
      Lastname
Phone
      Phone
```

Here the * is mentioned first group(orderinfo) and second group(Customerinfo). Here i wish to click the first group, which means the payment_method and subtotal should be displayed.

When the second group is clicked, the firstname, lastname and phone should be displayed. But here i have to run the app and click the first group and then the payment_method and subtotal is displayed successfully. After that some spaces also displayed here. Then i have to click the second group means first displayed some spaces after that only displayed firstname,lastname and phone. How can i resolve this error? Please explain to me in detail.

This is my layout file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment_method1"
     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
     android:text="payment_method"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/payment_method"
     android:paddingLeft="75px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:text="payment_method"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtotal1"
      android:text="subtotal"
     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtotal"
      android:text="subtotal"
     android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
                  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstname1"
     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
                   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstname"
     android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastname1"

     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastname"

     android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone1"
     android:paddingLeft="5px"
     android:textSize="15dip"

    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/phone"
     android:paddingLeft="65px"
     android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      </LinearLayout>


       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use the API demos?

they have some nice examples of how to do it.

check the `views/expandandable lists/` category.

surely you can customize it the way you want it...

the demos can be found (if you've downloaded them via the sdk manager) on `SDK_MANAGER_PATH/samples/android-##/ApiDemos` , where SDK_MANAGER_PATH is the path of the installation of the sdk manager , and the ## is the android target version of the sample (i usually use the latest) .

Comment: please give me some additional details with coding tutorial

Comment: i don't understand . do you mean you want to know how to run the sample api demos ?

Comment: i can't develop this layout problem.so please help me.how can i change the my layout file for my questions

Comment: please try to read the api demos . i agree that some of them are complex , but surely this one isn't. here: http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html . online code of the most basic one is on : http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/blobs/705a3ee3975877460c124d98eda12ae16dadd1a6/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.java